# center img with height=100% in a div of fixed height and auto width

Tags: javascript, html, css

sorry, i know this lots on this topic, but i couldnt find one where the img was 100% in height.

here's a jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BBQvd/3/

just trying to center it. i know this should be easy. javascript solutions are welcome.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to `.wrap`

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/M2AQ4/

Comment: ahh I was adding to the img like a moron. Thanks for that. /embarassed

Comment: If you were to add `display: block` to your image, you would then want to apply `margin: 0 auto;` to center it.